# Webview won't go back to original page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Basically I am trying to call the back button to goto the previous web page, how ever it seems  it isn't able to do so. I am not sure if I am missing a minor detail. This seems to work when I am on the original page click on a link then another link then push back button to get to the first link, but won't go back to original page(hope that make sense).

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 119,   self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 165)];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  webView.opaque = NO;
  [webView loadHTMLString:self.item.description baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.item.link]];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
  webView.delegate = self;
 webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34);
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:backButton];


   }

- (void)back {
[webView goBack];
  }
```

Comment: Are you declare UIWebViewDelegate in .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You do not give UIWebViewDelegate in .h file then first give it & then if your problem is not solve then simply comment this line & then check:
`webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` 
I run your code everything is fine but I run your code with comment that line.